# Android 12 Nearby Devices permission crashes app

Tags: android, kotlin, permissions, bluetooth, android-12

Yo,
I have an app that connects to Bluetooth devices (we specify the MAC address).
It targets API 28 and Compile SDK is 31.

This is all working fine however I just got a Pixel 6 Pro and the app crashes anytime I try to do anything Bluetooth related.
The crash says:
Need android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT permission

The app already has this permission in the Manifest. I can fix the crash but I have to go into the app permissions and allow permission for Nearby devices.

Is there something I have to do to get this working without having to explicitly allow the permission? On API 28 preferably too.
I tried what was in the Google Dev docs but seems to still crash.
I never had to allow this at runtime previously, is this required now on Android 12?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Google developer docs you have to ask for permission at runtime, see [this article](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) for reference.

Every time you want to perform an action that *may* be guarded by a permission, ask the user for permission, even if it was previously granted.